# Mostrar datos de un array en tabla

Tags: javascript, html, table

Me pueden ayudar a mostrar los datos del array skill de javascript y el de nivel, en una tabla que ya tengo creada en el html, intente crear una variable tabla y asignarle la etiqueta table del DOM, despues crear una fila y una columna y encapsular la fila dentro de la tabla y columna dentro de la fila. Adjunto codigo html.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Skills</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css"></link>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</head>
    <body>
        <section class="global">
            <div class="t_exp">
                <h2>Skills</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="prepro">
                <table class="tabla">
                    <tr>
                        <th>SKILL</th>
                        <th>NIVEL</th>
                    </tr>         
                </table>
            </div>
        </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

Adjunto codigo javascript

```
let skill = ["Javascript","Html, Css","jQuery, Typescript","Vuejs, Vuetify","Php","Mysql","Docker"]
let level = ["Medio","Medio","Medio","Medio","Bajo","Bajo","Bajo"]
let fila = document.createElement("tr")
let col = document.createElement("td")
let tabla = document.querySelector(".tabla")
tabla.appendChild(fila)
fila.appendChild(col)
skill.forEach((sk)=>{
    col.appendChild(sk)
})
```

Quiero que muestre en la columna izquierda las skills y al lado el nivel, les agradezco mucho

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debes ir creando celda a celda, luego cada celda la ingresas a la fila y cada fila a la tabla. Todo dentro del `for`

```js
let skill = ["Javascript","Html, Css","jQuery, Typescript","Vuejs, Vuetify","Php","Mysql","Docker"]
let level = ["Medio","Medio","Medio","Medio","Bajo","Bajo","Bajo"]


let tabla = document.querySelector(".tabla")

skill.forEach((sk,i)=>{
   let fila = document.createElement("tr");
   
   let col1 = document.createElement("td");
   col1.innerText = sk;
   
   let col2 = document.createElement("td");
   col2.innerText = level[i];
   
   fila.appendChild(col1);
   fila.appendChild(col2);
   
   tabla.appendChild(fila);
})
```

```html
<table class="tabla">
      <tr>
          <th>SKILL</th>
          <th>NIVEL</th>
      </tr>         
  </table>
```

Otra forma (creo que más simple) de realizar lo mismo, sería usar `innerHTML`. Para esto, agregue los `thead` y `tbody` correspondiente a la tabla

```js
let skill = ["Javascript","Html, Css","jQuery, Typescript","Vuejs, Vuetify","Php","Mysql","Docker"]
let level = ["Medio","Medio","Medio","Medio","Bajo","Bajo","Bajo"]


let tabla = document.querySelector(".tabla")

skill.forEach((sk,i)=>{
   tabla.innerHTML +=`
   <tr>
     <td>${sk}</td>
     <td>${level[i]}</td>
   </tr>`;
})
```

```html
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>SKILL</th>
        <th>NIVEL</th>
    </tr>
<thead>
<tbody class="tabla"></tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: por alguna razon no me muestra los datos del array..probé de las dos formas y no muestra..que podrá ser

Comment: @LimbertMolina Prueba mover el `<script src="main.js"></script>` y dejarlo entre `</section>` y `</body>`

Comment: ok ya pruebo grcias

Comment: ohhh ya me salio!!! ya se muestra muchisimas gracias

Comment: @LimbertMolina Me alegro te haya funcionado. El problema es que para modificar el documento (el DOM), este debe estar cargado. La carga comienza de arriba hacia abajo, tu javascript se ejecutaba antes que la tabla existiera, por eso al mover el scrip abajo (cuando la tabla ha sido cargada, se soluciona). Pero lo más recomendable es usar el evento `DOMContentLoaded` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/DOMContentLoaded_event

Comment: ok listo gracias por la gran explicación, muy detallada

Comment: @LimbertMolina Se agradece el +1 !! pero lo que te decía es que la marcaras como aceptada (es marcar con un visto verde a la izquierda de la respuesta). No es obligatorio ni votar ni aceptar, pero para la correcta retroalimentación del sitio deberías hacerlo. Las respuestas que son útiles le das un +1 y las respuesta que te ayudó a resolver el problema la aceptas con el visto verde

Comment: ok gracias por el dato